# how to build an aspnet6 + selenium + chrome docker image

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, openshift

I am learning the deeper parts of writing a **Dockerfile** to host Dot Net projects.

I would like to do the following when I "run" the launchsettings for docker:

- build/publish in docker
- combine 2 docker images as my base image (ignored for now)

  - mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
  - selenium/standalone-chrome
- copy the local publish directory and all its children to the /app directory in the container
- expose the internal http port as 8080, not the default 80
- run the app

What I have that is not working is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 8080 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080 
ENV Logging__Loglevel__Default=Debug 
ENV Logging__Loglevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore=Debug 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["Monitor.Web.csproj", "."] 
RUN dotnet restore "./Monitor.Web.csproj" 
COPY . ./
WORKDIR "/src/." 
RUN dotnet build "Monitor.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish Monitor.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false 

FROM base AS final 
COPY --from=publish /app/publish . 

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Monitor.Web.dll" ]
```

I know I am close for doing all of this local to my machine.  However, I also need to take into consideration pushing this out via an Azure Pipeline into OCP (Openshift Containers).  I do not think the `publish` portion will work in the pipeline as it does locally.  Thoughts?  Ideas?

TIA

---

ADDITION - tail end of dockerfile output:
[image]

---

ADDITION 02 - stdout logs

```
[16:23:00 INF] ===> Execute AuthCodeHybridGrantJob.Invoke(...) <s:>
[16:23:00 DBG] Execute AuthCodeHybridGrantJob.RunAtTimeOf <s:>
[16:23:00 DBG] -- CACHE: AuthCodeHybridGrantJob_Step01 found.  Expires in 14 minutes. <s:>
[16:23:00 DBG] RemoteWebDriver(new Uri($"http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities()) <s:>
[16:23:00 DBG] driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://localhost:49000); <s:>
[16:23:01 DBG] CACHE: Alert raised for AuthCodeHybridGrantJob_Step01 <s:>
[16:23:01 DBG] CACHE: Found value for AuthCodeHybridGrantJob_Step01 <s:>
[16:23:01 ERR] Job AuthCodeHybridGrantJob failed! <s:>
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.146)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Navigator.GoToUrl(String url)
   at CIAM.Monitor.Web.Jobs.AuthCodeHybridGrantJob.RunAtTimeOf(DateTime now) in C:\Repos\CIAM\CIAM\CIAM.Monitor.Web\Jobs\AuthCodeHybridGrantJob.cs:line 67
[16:23:01 INF] ===> AuthCodeHybridGrantJob.Invoke(...) failed! <s:>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What's missing? Any logs?

Comment: Looking at the logs you provided, I think there is at least one step before achieving what you want as a goal. The dotnet publish command should be executed in an image with the SDK, not in a dotnet runtime image. You need to change the dockerfile first line to use an SDK image, like:

" FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env "

Comment: Tried adding in the SDK image and the build was successful.  However, the Selenium part is "not found" when running the image.  I am ref: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/Standalone/Dockerfile and poking around my image in term.  The supervisor directory is just not there.